# Copy construct and assignment operator in the derived class

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, derived-class, assignment-operator

I have a class (class A) which inherits another class (class B).

```
class A: public B
```

Class B disabled copy construct and assignment operator (due to not allow a copy).

```
private:
 B(const B&);
 B& operator=(const B&);
```

My question is that should I also disable copy construct and assignment operator in the derived class as well or is it okay if I did not define both.

Comment: Depends on *how* did B disable copy-ctor.

Comment: @jrok Why?  Regardless of how B disabled copy and assignment, they're disabled by default in the derived class.

Comment: @JamesKanze I'm counting putting it in `protected` section as "disabling" it.

Comment: What is the difference putting it in private or protected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is rather, should you re-enable it.  If any base or member is noncopyable, your class will be noncopyable by default.  Generally, you won't want to remove it, because it will be difficult or impossible to give it reasonable semantics.  But there are notable exceptions: if the base class is abstract, for example, you may want to enable the copy constructor (but not assignment) in the derived class in order to support cloning.

Comment: In case I have a pointer variable in the derived class, I got a warning that I should define copy construct and assignment operator. Should I consider another solution (i.e. without any pointer)? or is okay if I define them and disable them as well in the derived class?

Comment: @AvbAvb If copy and assignment have been disabled in the base class, and not re-enabled, the warning is simply wrong.  I'd turn it off (and maybe complain to the compiler vendor).

Answer (score 3):

Subclasses should have the same or stricter [preconditions, post conditions and invariants] than their parent classes. This is the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). So, you should not re-enable copy construction etc/whatever in the derived class, since you will be loosening the contract of the base class.

If you find you need to do it (or would really like to do it), then it may be a sign that you need to rethink your design.

Comment: I do not want to re-enable them. I am just asking whether I should also disable them in the derived class or is it okay if I do not do anything in the derived class.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that you already knew that the default behavior was that the derived class would "inherit" the contract of the base class in terms of copy construction and assignment. It would have been clearer if you explicitly stated your intent e.g. "I want Derived to have the same restrictions as Base, what do I do in Base?", to which I would reply "Nothing". all good.

Answer (score 0):

Disallowing copy-constructor and assignment operator of base class will cause that the copy-constructor and assignment operator of derived class won't be usable as well:

```
class B {
public:
    B() { }
private:
    B(const B&);
    B& operator=(const B&);
};

class A : public B { };
```

In this case you don't need to explicitly disallow these for derived class, since the default implementation will have to use the parent's implementation first. So if you don't try to access these in your code:

```
int main() {
    A a;
}
```

it will be perfectly valid. However if you try to copy:

```
int main() {
    A a;
    A a2 = A(a);
}
```

compiler will complain about class `A` trying to access private members of `B` (however semantically the second scenario shouldn't happen).